# QueryException: General error: 1 no such table: {table_name} (SQL: select * from "{table_name}")

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

- Laravel Version: 5.7
- PHP Version: 7.2
- Database Driver: sqlite
- Database: memory

All testing on PHPUnit was working completely fine. But when I added `View::share` in `AppServiceProvider` then all the PHPUnit tests failed.

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        \View::share('categories', \App\Models\Category::all());
    }
}
```

**Error**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: categories (SQL: select * from "categories")

I have already used `RefreshDatabase` in my all test.

Please guide me, how can I fix this. Where should I call `View::share` in Laravel app so, all tests should pass.

Comment: rerun `php artisan migrate` and double check your tables in your database. then please post what you get.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to the fact that the database doesnt even exists perhaps and provider boot is assuming that database/table its up and running.

Secure it a bit more by wrapping it

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
       if(\Schema::hasTable('categories'){
        \View::share('categories', \App\Models\Category::all());
       }
    }
}
```